# Posting Excel Data to a XML Web Service

Tags: xml, web-services, excel, toolkit, vba

Right now I can post 1 xml record to a web service via Excel and a few lines of code using the, "MSDN Web Services Toolkit 2.0" but I need the ability to post about 100 records at a time.

Issues:

- So I think I need a vba loop with "pauses" because I think the web service "response" needs to be removed/cleared out after xml each record is posted.
- I need an approach to call the XML Data for about 100 records:
  either I need to call the data off the second Excel tab that has a XSD applied to it (note, the XSD excel produces is slightly off so that concerns me) or
  I need to call a text file that has all the XML data or another way?

Trying to keep this dirt simple to import some data into an application via a web service from an Excel Sheet.  The toolkit did most of the heavy lifting now I just need a way to loop through 100 records.

Thx!

```
**Code so far that posts 1 record:**

Private Sub insPat_Click()
Dim info As New clsws_FDirect
Dim addpat As String
Dim response As String

addpat = Range("B10").Text
response = info.wsm_PatientAdd(addpat)
Set responserange = Range("B11")
responserange.Value = response

End Sub


**Correct XSD:**
<Patient>
<FacID>TEST</FacID>
<PatID>99</PatID>
<PatLName>IMPORT</PatLName>
<PatFName>MISTER</PatFName>
<Allergy>Sulfites</Allergy>
<Floor>11</Floor>
<NsID>1F</NsID>
<Room>111</Room>
<Bed>1</Bed>
</Patient>
```

Comment: Have you considered having the web service or some other code read _from_ the spreadsheet, instead of having the spreadsheet push the data to the web service? Because that toolkit is obsolete and unsupported.

Comment: The basic thing is to use a more powerful technology. VBA is much less powerful than .NET, so try to use .NET, not VBA.

Comment: I am open for suggestions, most of the other code examples I found were ways to receive multiple records from a web service but weren't "posting" anything substantial but a few variables.  Originally, I explored SSIS to do this task but that got complicated quickly and again those examples weren't posting lots of records to the web service.  My coding skills are limited so I was hoping for a little help on the VBA loop and then calling it a day.  Thx for the reply!

Comment: If you can use SSIS, then do so. It can read the Excel spreadsheet in a Data Flow, manipulate the data if necessary, then send each row to the service. Use a Script Component for the latter. It can use a Web Reference and call the service once for each row.